# Get full data view for two tables in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hue

I have two tables in Hive (`arch` and `noarch`) with the following structure:

| Table1Arch | Table2NoArch |
| --- | --- |
| tr_id | tr_id |
| res_id | res_id |
| info_json | info_json |
|  | created_at |
|  | updated_at |

I need to get a full data view `arch` + `noarch` and join them by `res_id`.

I tried to do different variations of left joins but I was getting either results from `arch` and nothing from `noarch` or vice versa. I guess I should have used `union all`, but struggling to write it correctly.

Could you please help me with the right query?

EDIT:

I'd like to get kinda united view for these two tables when I search for particular `res_id`s.

Say I have the following data:

| Entry1Arch | Entry2Arch |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 111 | 222 |
| {"something 1"} | {"something 2"} |

| Entry3NoArch | Entry4NoArch |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 |
| 333 | 444 |
| {"something 3"} | {"something 4"} |
| 2021-10-03 21:01:44.0 | 2021-10-04 21:02:43.0 |
| 2021-10-03 21:01:44.0 | 2021-10-04 21:02:43.0 |

The ultimate goal is to get full data from both tables: 111 + 222 + 333 + 444).

Comment: What result do you need? Please provide input data example from both tables and expected result

Comment: @leftjoin updated, please let me know if it's helpful

Comment: and what if both tables contain the same res_id?

Comment: Ah, thank you, my bad. Query is not correct then. I want basically the union of these two tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL:

```
select tr_id, res_id, info_json, created_at, updated_at, src
from
(select tr_id, res_id, info_json, created_at, updated_at, 'NoArch' as src 
  from Table2NoArch

union all

select tr_id, res_id, info_json, null created_at, null updated_at, 'Arch' as src 
  from Table1Arch
)u
where res_id in (111,333,444)
```

created_at and updated_at are absent in one Table1Arch, NULLs are selected, you can use current_timestamp or current_date instead.

Added src column, so you can easily find out the source of data.

Comment: ..and to be specific, if I want some particular ids for both tables?

Comment: @Stranger95 you can put union into subquery or view and then use filter. Updated the answer. predicates will be pushed into each query in union.

Comment: thanks a lot. Do you also know how to cope with `FAILED: SemanticException Schema of both sides of union should match` ?

Comment: @Stranger95 both queries should have the same number of columns and the same types. you can cast columns if they are of different types. for example cast(null as timestamp) as created_at .... to match timestamp type from other query if it is timestamp

Comment: @Stranger95 check all columns types and cast accordingly, nulls also should be cast to the same type.